# How do you decide a chord?

Tags: chords

This is from Schubert Impromptu Op.90 No.2 in Eb major: 
[image]

How do you decide the chord for the 3rd bar? 
I know Db13 is probably not right for it, but how can you tell it's not Db13? It has all the notes for that chord.

Generally, how do you choose the **main** notes of a melody to tell its chord?

Comment: That bar contains an entire scale run! Obviously a simple "which notes occur in the bar" is not a sufficient criterion for harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main notes are usually found on the main emphasised parts of a bar. In 4/4 they're beats 1 and 3. Here, in 9/8 they're on beats 1, 2 and 3 - the notes F, Ab and Eb respectively.

This gives the 'chord notes' of Db, F, Ab and Eb, which tend to constitute a Db add9.

Db13 has 1,3,5,b7,9,11 and 13 in it technically, so just about every note in the scale! We tend not to consider each and every note in a melody line as being potentially part of the underlying harmony, it's way too complex, and inaccurate to boot. Thus, I'm saying it's *not* Db13 !

Comment: Given the context, Classical music, I'd think that this would be a Db7 chord, not a Db add9.  While chord tones often fall on the strong beats, that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like a straightforward Db7, the dominant seventh chord to Gb major, which follows immediately.